# Как заставить работать min-width,max-width в %?

Tags: html, css

```
<table>
    <td class="left">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="middle">&nbsp;</td>
    <td class="right">&nbsp;</td>
</table>

table{width:100%;border:1px solid red;height:100px;}
.left{background:red;min-width:90%;}
.middle{background:orange}
.right{background:blue;}
```

Почему не работает min-width:90%; или как можно обойти эту проблему?Если минималка указана в px-все работает.Спасибо Вам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Ко всем элементам, кроме встроенных и таблиц](http://htmlbook.ru/css/min-width)

Внутрь ячейки нужно поместить DIV для которого задать минимальную ширину.

Comment: Спасибо.Так мне нужно резиновая в % минималка.Оно ведь будет брать от TD, а мне нужно от Table;

Answer (score 0):

```
.left{background:red;width:90%;}
```